# Add username to Spark's log4j

Tags: python, logging, apache-spark, log4j, py4j

I have a python script which uses Spark, so I decided to use Spark's own log4j to do the logging for my script too. However I want to add the current OS username to the logging pattern, and possibly even other parameters.

There are some solutions where I should extend log4j classes etc. but since I am using python, and beside that, not even my own log4j but Spark's, is there a simple way to add these variables?

If not simpler, maybe I can add some variables from inside the script in the beginning, and then insert the variable into the log4j pattern? I can call the logger for messages through levels, like `logger.info` or similar, but I don't know what other functions are accessible through the py4j gateway from python, and I couldn't find any good documentation for this.